# C# get Windows CD Key

Tags: c#, windows-7, registry

I've been using the below code in order to get the Windows License Key. It worked pretty well a long time. But now I discovered that it works on Windows XP (x86) but **not** on Windows 7 x64.

**Reason:** The `DigitalProductID` regisitry value contains only zeroes within the range we are looking for on the 64 bit operating system. Therefore the result it `BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB`. Why is it so and how can I fix this?

```
    public static string LicenseCDKey
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] rpk = (byte[])Registry.LocalMachine
                   .OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion")
                   .GetValue("DigitalProductId");
                string serial = "";
                const string possible = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789";
                for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
                {
                    int accu = 0;
                    for (int a = 0; a < 15; a++)
                    {
                        accu <<= 8;
                        accu += rpk[66 - a];
                        rpk[66 - a] = (byte)(accu / 24 & 0xff);
                        accu %= 24;
                    }
                    serial = possible[accu] + serial;
                    if (i % 5 == 4 && i < 24)
                    {
                        serial = "-" + serial;
                    }
                }
                return serial;
            }
            catch
            {
                return ErrorString;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you change the output to x64 instead of Any CPU for the platform target?

Comment: Nope, as I replied to both answers below I'm using AnyCPU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As **user287107** pointed out x86 applications (32 bit) running on a x64 operating system are using a different registry (registry view).

In order to access the x64 registry you have a few options:

1. Change your platform target to x64 (Visual Studio project settings).
2. If you are using .Net Framework 4.0 you could use the `RegistryKey` class and `RegistryView` enum to access the x64 registry.

   ```
   RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine,
                                             RegistryView.Registry64);

   string keyPath = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion";
   byte[] rpk = (byte[])key.OpenSubKey(keyPath).GetValue("DigitalProductId");
   ```
3. If you are not using the .Net Framework 4.0 and you do not want to set your platform target to x64 you have to use Interop (`RegOpenKeyEx()` Win32 API function with the `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` flag) to access the x64 registry.

**BEGIN EDIT**

I've just found an interesting [post](http://windows7forums.com/windows-7-software/52182-i-have-problen-find-product-key-windows-7-i-need-help-2.html) explaining why the DigitialProductId key could be null/empty:

1. You are using an Volume License Key to activate your Windows 7 operating system. The VLC key is deleted from the registry after activation.
2. Someone deleted the registry key (modified the content of this key) manually using the command `slmgr –cpky`

**END EDIT**

Comment: And, as posted in user287107's answer, I do use AnyCPU, but it is still not working. Try the code yourself and see.

Comment: @DevilsChild: Is the client computer activated using an Volume License Key?

Comment: @DevilsChild: On my x64 bit Windows 7 machine, the code above returns the correct license key.

Comment: I'm not using a volume license key. This is a screenshot (partially censored) from my DigitalProductId http://xload.dev-ch.com/95a4322173acc41f/screen396.jpg

Comment: @DevilsChild: If you do not use a volume license key then I think the DigitalProductId was deleted with the slmgr -cpky command. Note, the registry key still exists but the DigitalProductId is modified. As a result you get BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB.

Comment: Ok, so it's not an error in my code, but on the user's machine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

32 bit applications use a different registry path

a 32 bit application accesses the registry path in 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
where it does not find the product key.

changing the processor type to x64 worked for me to get the real key.

Comment: I use AnyCPU indeed, still with no effort. With x86 i would not get any key at all.